# Unable to get required JDBC Exception

Tags: java, jdbc, exception

I have created a login form using java servlets and jsp's. The login information such as username and password is saved in Database.
My question is that when a user enters the information that my java class fails to find in database I dont get the exception. How could I create an exception if the login data isnt available in Db?

```
public boolean loginValidator(String e, String p) throws SQLException {

    String userName = e;
    String password = p;
    boolean validate = false;
    try{
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? and password = ?");
    ps.setString(1, userName);
    ps.setString(2, password);

    ResultSet rst = ps.executeQuery();

    while (rst.next()) {
        validate = (rst.getString("email").equals(userName)) && ((rst.getString("password").equals(password)));
    }}
    catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        validate = false;
    }


return validate;
}
```

This is actually a method in my java class that validates and send boolean type to a servlet and later servlet decides to direct or restrict the access to application subject to the boolean type returned.

PS: A new learner of javaWeb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And a learner of SQL, right? Because there is NO exception, if there is no such line in the DB table. The query just returns empty `ResultSet`. So you have to check, whether the result set is empty or not (and then alternatively check the email and password - but that is IMHO superfluous).

```
public boolean loginValidator(String userName, String password) {
    try{
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? and password = ?");
        ps.setString(1, userName);
        ps.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet rst = ps.executeQuery();
        return rst.next(); // whether DB contains such record
    } catch(SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace(); // TIP: use logging
    }
    return false;
}
```

Btw. I would strongly recommend you **NOT** to store plaintext passwords in the DB.

Comment: please elucidate your statement  "Btw. I would strongly recommend you NOT to store plaintext passwords in the DB."

Comment: How should I store passwords than?

Comment: Passwords have to be stored encrypted, i.e. you have to store an hash of the password. I would recommend using [BCrypt](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.html) - really simple usage and a very strong algorithm.